# Append data in Json file

Tags: android, json, append

I have this type of JSON:

```
{
    "stampi": 
    [
        {
            "nome": "Ovale Piccolo 18.2x13.5cm",
            "lunghezza": 18.2,
            "larghezza": 13.5,
            "altezza": 4,
            "volume": 786.83
        },                      
         {
            "nome": "Ovale Grande 22.5x17.4cm",
            "lunghezza": 22.5,
            "larghezza": 17.4,
            "altezza": 4,
            "volume": 1246.54
        }                                                 
    ]


}
```

and normally I read with this code:

```
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("stampi.json")));

            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close(); // stop reading
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
        myjson_stampi = sb.toString();
```

and after use the array inside the program.
I have create a menu that add new value inside the JSON file but i have a problem ...this is the code:

> ```
>               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
>               BufferedReader br = null;
>               try {
>                   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("stampi.json")));
>
>                   String temp;
>                   while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
>                       sb.append(temp);
>               } catch (IOException e) {
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               } finally {
>                   try {
>                       br.close(); // stop reading
>                   } catch (IOException e) {
>                       e.printStackTrace();
>                   }
>               }           
>               myjson_stampi = sb.toString();      
>
>               try {                       
>                   // Creating JSONObject from String
>                   JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjson_stampi);
>
>                   // Creating JSONArray from JSONObject
>                   JSONArray objNames = jsonObjMain.names();
>                   System.out.println(objNames.toString());
>
>                   jsonArray_stampi = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("stampi");
>
>                   int num_elem = jsonArray_stampi.length();
>
>                    jsonObjMain.put( "nome","prova");
>                    jsonObjMain.put( "lunghezza",22);
>                    jsonObjMain.put( "larghezza", 10);
>                    jsonObjMain.put( "altezza", 4);
>                    jsonObjMain.put( "volume", 10.5);
>                    jsonArray_stampi.put( jsonObjMain );
>                    try {
>
>                           FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:\\test.json");
>                           //file.write(jsonArray_stampi.);
>                           file.write( JSON.stringify(jsonArray_stampi) );
>                           file.flush();
>                           file.close();
>
>                       } catch (IOException e) {
>                           e.printStackTrace();
>                       }
>
>               } catch (JSONException e) {
>                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               }   
>
>           }           });
> ```

why can't work correctly?
the num_elem variable are 2 always..help me!

thx Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new JSONObject and then add new data to it and then append to the existing object.

```
JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjson_stampi); //Your existing object
JSONObject jO = new JSONObject(); //new Json Object
JSONArray jsonArray_stampi = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("stampi"); //Array where you wish to append

//Add data
jO.put( "nome","prova");
jO.put( "lunghezza",22);
jO.put( "larghezza", 10);
jO.put( "altezza", 4);
jO.put( "volume", 10.5);

//Append
jsonArray_stampi.put(jO);
```

Also you should write back the complete jsonObject back to the file.

```
file.write(JSON.stringify(jsonObjMain));
```

Comment: why do you use jO? (new Object) , I don't understand how work, after the function put the object jO is not used!

Comment: sorry i forgot to replace your code. please check the edited code.

Comment: ok thx, but which is the best metod to WRITE in the file I'm looking for an example, but no foud..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to write to a file called `c:\\test.json`. Try using the proper Android way to write to files with `openFileOutput`. Examples are [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ok, if the file is inside the ASSETS? and i want to append data in file that exist.

Comment: If you checkout that link I sent you, it details opening internally and externally stored files. You can open a file for writing the same way you open it for reading.